# How to create a dataset of rows that don't match between 2 datasets in r

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge 2 different datasets by row and they look like this:

| X | y |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 4 |
| c | 7 |
| d | 8 |

and my second dataset is

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | 9 |
| j | 4 |
| c | 6 |
| f | 8 |

I can merge them by rows, but what I am looking for is to create a second dataset that includes all the values that weren't matched, since my datasets are of unequal size, and I want to see the values that don't match between the two datasets.

So I want an output that looks like:

| X_1 | y | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 9 |
| c | 7 | 6 |

and a dataset that includes only stuff that did not get matched from the first table(which we can assume is longer than the second one)

| X | y |
| --- | --- |
| b | 4 |
| d | 8 |

Is there any function that can help me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `inner_join/anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("X" = "A"))
  X y B
1 a 1 9
2 c 7 6
anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("X" = "A"))
   X y
1 b 4
2 d 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining two data with common values only, one way you can use is `merge()` :

```
merge(data1,data2,by.x = "X",by.y = "A")
  X y B
1 a 1 9
2 c 7 6
```

To extract the unmatched values:

```
data1[!(data1$X %in% data2$A),]
  X y
2 b 4
4 d 8
```